# knife solo is removing cooklbook/docker/recipes/ folder - Docker provisioning with Chef

Tags: chef-infra, knife, knife-solo, librarian

I am trying to provisione Docker containers with Chef, I am using knife solo and librarian-chef.

I get docker cookbook and create a test recipe, but when execute `knife solo bootstrap nodo@192.168.150.78` return

```
Enter the password for nodo@192.168.1.7: 

Starting Chef Client, version 12.6.0
Compiling Cookbooks...

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
--------------------------------
could not find recipe default for cookbook docker


Running handlers:
[2016-01-22T13:54:17-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-01-22T13:54:17-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 00 seconds
[2016-01-22T13:54:17-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-01-22T13:54:17-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-01-22T13:54:17-05:00] ERROR: could not find recipe default for cookbook docker
[2016-01-22T13:54:17-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
ERROR: RuntimeError: chef-solo failed. See output above.
```

and cookbook/docker/recipe folder and default.rb file are deleted.

To test, I try with a apache cookbook and this works.

Can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of [the Docker cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker) does not include a default recipe. Please follow its README to see how to use it.